# Inconsistent results on Android SQLite query

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-database

I'm experiencing some unexpected inconsistencies on the result of a SQL query on Android.

Given the following Schema (which is pretty simple):

```
public static final String TABLE_TOTD = "totd";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
public static final String COLUMN_TG = "tg";
public static final String COLUMN_EX = "ex";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "TOTD.db";

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE "
        + TABLE_TOTD + "("
            + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + COLUMN_TG + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + COLUMN_EX + " TEXT"
        + ");";
```

And the database being initialized and filled with a few sample texts:

```
    SQLiteDatabase db = mdbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_TG, "This is a text (1)");
    values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_EX, "Example goes here");

    db.insert(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_TOTD, null, values);
    [...]
```

I'm retrieving inconsistent results when querying with SQLiteDatabase.query()
The following code does what it's expected to do, by returning a Cursor with the first row of the table.

```
    String[] projection = null;
    String selection = "id = 1";
    String[] selectionArgs = null;
    Cursor cursor = db.query(
            MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_TOTD,
            projection,
            selection,
            selectionArgs,
            null, null, null);
```

It works exactly the same by changing the `selection` and `selectionArgs` like this:

```
    String selection = "id = ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = {"1"};
```

But now, differently than expected, by performing the following changes, the returned Cursor will now be empty:

```
    String selection = "? = ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = {"id", "1"};
```

Actually, trying to push anything that is not the `"1"` into the arguments will cause the query to return an empty cursor.

I've tried the following:

```
    String selection = "? = 1";
    String[] selectionArgs = {"id"};

    String selection = "id ? 1";
    String[] selectionArgs = {"="};

    String selection = "?";
    String[] selectionArgs = {"id = 1"}; //This is where I couldn't take it anymore...
```

Now, I'm open-minded to any sort of explanations about this. My code works, and I know that I can put all my arguments on the `selection` string since they do not contain any forbidden characters.
I only wanted to know, why isn't it working, and why isn't there any mention to this clear limitation on the developer documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the selection argument is the `WHERE` clause of your sqlite query. When you execute the query with a ? it will look this argument in the selectionArgs String array. However you can only specified the value as ? and not the key. A few valid example:

```
String selection = "id = ?";
String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{"1"};
```

is similar to

```
String selection = "id = 1";
String[] selectionArgs = null;
```

However you can not do

```
String selection = "? = ?";
```

You can also specify multiple ? in the selection.

```
String selection = "id = ? AND carId = ?";
String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{"1", "2"};
```

From the documentation:

> You may include ?s in selection, which will be replaced by the values
>   from selectionArgs, in order that they appear in the selection. The
>   values will be bound as Strings.

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query(boolean, java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query(boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

Comment: It does make sense that only the values can be replaced on the `select` statement, yet this behavior isn't explained very well on the documentation... I'm so used to C-like string formatting, that I didn't expected these limitations on this specific call.